# Error in ng serve command. ./ node module/@angular-devkit/build

Tags: css, node.js, angular, saas, angular-devkit

`node` version `14.15.0` and `angular` version `12.0.5`;
earlier it worked fine but after reinstallation of `angular` and `nodejs` it shows this error on `ng serve` command.

```
ERROR in ./src/assets/styles/style.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--15-3!./src/assets/styles/style.scss)
Module Error (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError: D:\node-v15.11.0-win-x64\ssc1\src\assets\styles\icons\material-design-iconic-font\css\materialdesignicons.min.css:1:86: Can't resolve '..//fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.eot' in 'D:\node-v15.11.0-win-x64\ssc1\src\assets\styles\icons\material-design-iconic-font\css'
```

If anybody know the solution please tell me how to solve this issue
[image of error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58vmH.png)

Comment: [DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: I am thinking `PostCSS` does not like comments like `/* ... */`. Try removing one and see if one of the errors goes away.

Comment: Jaya, you should **not** put .css in assets folder (create another folder). In Angular you should add the styles adding in `angular.json` file:https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#styles-and-scripts-configuration